# How to avoid inplace removal of modification of a Networkx graph

Tags: python-3.x, graph, networkx

I've a netwrokx graph, I'm trying to remove the edges of the graph using `remove_edges`.
I want to remove each edge in the original graph and post-process `H` to get further stats like edges connected to the edge that has been removed.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# fig 1
n=10
G = nx.gnm_random_graph(n=10, m=10, seed=1)
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
for e in [[5, 0], [3, 6]]:
    H = G.remove_edge(e[0], e[1])
    nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
    plt.show()
```

In the above, the edge is removed inplace in G. So for the second iteration, the original graph is no
longer present. How can this be avoided? I want to retain the original graph for every iteration and instead store the graph that results after edge removal in another copy, H.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

EDIT: Based on what's suggested below

```
n=10
G = nx.gnm_random_graph(n=10, m=10, seed=1)
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
G_copy = G.copy()

for e in [[5, 0], [3, 6]]:
    print(G_copy.edges())
    H = G_copy.remove_edge(e[0], e[1])
    nx.draw(G_copy, with_labels=True)
    plt.show()
```

print(G_copy.edges())

Obtained output:

```
[(0, 6), (0, 7), (0, 5), (1, 4), (1, 7), (1, 9), (2, 9), (3, 6), (3, 4), (6, 9)]
[(0, 6), (0, 7), (1, 4), (1, 7), (1, 9), (2, 9), (3, 6), (3, 4), (6, 9)]
```

Expected:

```
[(0, 6), (0, 7), (0, 5), (1, 4), (1, 7), (1, 9), (2, 9), (3, 6), (3, 4), (6, 9)]
[(0, 6), (0, 7), (0, 5), (1, 4), (1, 7), (1, 9), (2, 9), (3, 6), (3, 4), (6, 9)]
```

Comment: There is no `H` in your code.

Comment: @DYZ Please check the edit

Comment: `G.remove_edge` returns the original graph `G`, not a copy of it. See my answer.

Comment: G_copy is a copy that is modified in a loop. You print it before and after the modification. Surely, the edge list is different. Your question now is very confusing.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I was trying to freeze the modification in G and instead store the modified graph in a new variable. I now realize this doesn't work. Writing the G.remove_edges() in a different function and passing the original G to this function helps.

Comment: Why is the obtained ouput not the expected? You're removing those two edges, hence they are no longer present in the list. Whereas `G` remains unchaned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a copy of the original graph and modify the copy:

```
H = G.copy()
...
H.remove_edge(e[0], e[1])
```